# Get the name of an overloaded function passed as an argument at run-time

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, visual-c++, pointer-to-member

Assume all includes are defined, please go through the code structure defined below.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, void*> callbackReg;

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int a)
    {
        //impl
    }
    void foo(int a, int b)
    {
        //impl
    }
    void foo(int a, double d)
    {
        //impl
    }

};


template<class Instance , typename Function>
void register_func(Instance& obj, Function func)
{
    /* have to store function name as the key and 
     - pointer to raw member function pointer as the value, 
     - in callbackReg Map */
    // ---> Point B
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a;
    register_evt(a, &A::foo); //---> point A
    system("Pause");
}
```

---

### Problems and Discussions

1. @ `Point A` how to resolve function name scope resolution issue which means how to call a overloaded function/pointer to such function ? without inline static cast since it makes bit ugly and messy.
2. @ `Point B` assume we have fixed overload name resolutuin issue and now we have to store ***member funtion name*** and ***its pointer value*** in `callbackReg` map.

I know may this could bad cumbersome approach but, is this feasible in C++? or else is there any way to store *`raw memeber funtion pointers`* with some other key-value in order to use them as `callbacks`.Since at `debug` time,debugger already knows what is the function name passed as `register_func` template fucntion argument.
Please look at the image attached. 
[image]

- Therefore,simply, how can we implement *callback `register`/**`unregister`*** scenario using only raw member/non-member function pointers?

### (Please if the solution or methodology is a *cross-platform* approach that would be grateful, at least Win32 based)

Comment: C++ doesn't have [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection). You can't get a functions name from a pointer to the function. The usual solution is to pass the name as an argument together with the function. The debugger can get the name from extra information that the compiler saves together with the executable program file (in it or as a separate file), but this information is typically not available in release builds.

Comment: "how to resolve function name scope resolution issue which means how to call a overloaded function/pointer to such function ?" using `static_cast` if you find it messy then avoid your approach to the problem.

Comment: You can use a macro for that `#define RegisterFunc(obj,func) register_func_and_name(obj,func,#func)`

Comment: "Since at debug time,debugger already knows what is the function name passed..." so you want your program to work only when compiled with debug enabled?

Comment: @Oliv how that will help with overload resolution?

Comment: @Oliv you mentioning a static/compile-time operation, don't we have run-time option?

Comment: @Slava no I want it run in release/optimization enabled mode.

Comment: Then the fact that debugger shows something is unrelated to solution you may have.

Comment: Maybe a library as this [libunwind](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/libunwind/) could provide what you are looking for.

Comment: [`SymFromAddr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symfromaddr) could retrieves symbol information for the specified address to get the function name. But it needs to provide symbol file.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Thank you I will try that, but this is only works with debug mode right?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it just needs symbol file.

Comment: No. Generating a symbol file does not require any particular project configuration. You can (and usually do) create symbol information for release builds as well. Although if you *do* want to go down that route, you will have to ship debug symbols along with your applications. Those databases are usually tens and hundreds of megabytes in size, and ease reverse engineering of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [boost backtrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.getting_function_information_fro):

> boost::stacktrace::frame provides information about functions. You may construct that class from function pointer and get the function name at runtime

Comment: thank you very much,can we implement it by ourselves ?

Comment: @Buddhika Yes. You need knowledge about the executable file fomat and debug informations. Boost is open source, so just watch inside the source code. Hopefully it is well documented.

Comment: @Oliv any better pattern for `register` and `unregister` such raw function pointer callback approach?